# MySQL Error - Not adding to database every time the query is called

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

> mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounting(transid, unixtime, username,
>   description, amount, type, time) VALUES('$randomtransid', '0', '$yti',
>   'BLVD Offer Completion', '$theamount', 'points', '$dateandtime')");

The example code above is my MySQL query but it does not get added into the MySQL database every time I refresh the page...

What can I do?

=============
SOLVED:

After adding `"mysql_error();",` this is the error:

> Query failed: Duplicate entry ... for key 'uniqueness'

I fixed this by changing the structure of my database table.

Thanks

=============

Comment: Do you have unique indexes? What is the error reported? BTW SQL injection + deprecated library

Comment: add mysql_error() to catch the error.

Comment: And please use http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php (prepared statements). The way you're using queries is an open door for SQL injections..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space after your table name. Otherwise it looks like a function.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounting(transid, unixtime, username, description, amount, type, time) VALUES('$randomtransid', '0', '$yti', 'BLVD Offer Completion', '$theamount', 'points', '$dateandtime')");
                                ^^^^^^^ 
                                  HERE
```

Should be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO accounting (transid, unixtime, username, description, amount, type, time) VALUES('$randomtransid', '0', '$yti', 'BLVD Offer Completion', '$theamount', 'points', '$dateandtime')");
```

A few notes:

1. If you checked for error in your code you would have caught this quickly and easily. Always look for and handle errors. In your case a call to [`mysql_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) would have done the trick.
2. [You shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).
3. Since I can't see you handling this explicitly in your code I must assume you are
   wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174).